# Ignore other results if a resultset has been found

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

To start, take this snippet as an example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM StatsVehicle 
WHERE ((ReferenceMakeId = @referenceMakeId)
 OR @referenceMakeId IS NULL)
```

This will fetch and filter the records if the variable @referenceMakeId is not null, and if it is null, will fetch all the records. In other words, it is taking the first one into consideration if @referenceMakeId is not null.

I would like to add a further restriction to this, how can I achieve this?

For instance

```
(ReferenceModelId = @referenceModeleId) OR
(
    (ReferenceMakeId = @referenceMakeId) OR
    (@referenceMakeId IS NULL)
)
```

If @referenceModelId is not null, it will only need to filter by ReferenceModelId, and ignore the other statements inside it. If I actually do this as such, it returns all the records. Is there anything that can be done to achieve such a thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this?

```
SELECT * FROM StatsVehicle WHERE 
( 
    -- Removed the following, as it's not clear if this is beneficial
    -- (@referenceModeleId IS NOT NULL) AND 
    (ReferenceModelId = @referenceModeleId)
) OR
(@referenceModeleId IS NULL AND 
 (
    (ReferenceMakeId = @referenceMakeId) OR
    (@referenceMakeId IS NULL)
 )
)
```

Comment: Actually, this part `(@referenceModeleId IS NOT NULL AND ReferenceModelId = @referenceModeleId)` can be shorter: `(ReferenceModelId = @referenceModeleId)`, since nothing equals null, not even null itself.

Comment: I'd love to know if there's any speed benefit one way or the other... Do you know if a null check is more or less optimal than an equality check? (And if short circuiting of the checks can occur?)

Comment: I know for a fact that short circuiting **may** occur but are **not guaranteed in any way.** You can't trust short circuiting in t-sql.

Comment: Thanks it works @MattFellows
Adding `@referenceModeleId IS NOT NULL` is necessary for performance, as it will ignore the other condition.

Tested it with some millions of records!

Comment: I've just ran a simple test on a huge table I keep for testing performance stuff like that. Adding the test for `is not null` **does not help**. a table/index scan/seek was in all of the following statements:
`SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE @CharCol IS NOT NULL AND CharCol = @CharCol`,
`SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE CharCol = @CharCol`,
`SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE @IntCol IS NOT NULL AND IntCol = @IntCol`,
`SELECT * FROM Tbl WHERE IntCol = @IntCol`
This is where both @CharCol and @IntCol are null, of course

Comment: Interesting - I guess it may depend on the situation as short circuiting is not guaranteed?  I've removed it anyway as It's not necessary for the code to function...

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
SELECT * FROM StatsVehicle 
WHERE ReferenceModelId = @referenceModeleId OR
(
@referenceModeleId IS NULL AND 
    (
    @referenceMakeId IS NULL OR
    ReferenceMakeId = @referenceMakeId
    )
)
```

However, you should note that this types of queries (known as catch-all queries) tend to be less efficient then writing a single query for every case.

This is due to the fact that SQL Server will cache the first query plan that might not be optimal for other parameters.

You might want to consider using the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` [query hint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181714.aspx), or braking down the stored procedure to pieces that will each handle the specific conditions (i.e one select for null variables, one select for non-null).

For more information, read [this article](http://sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/).

Answer (score 0):

> If @referenceModelId is not null, it will only need to filter by
>   ReferenceModelId, and ignore the other statements inside it. If I
>   actually do this as such, it returns all the records. Is there
>   anything that can be done to achieve such a thing?

You can think of using a `CASE` for good short circuit mechanism

```
WHERE
    CASE 
        WHEN @referenceModelId is not null AND ReferenceModelId = @referenceModeleId THEN 1
        WHEN @referenceMakeId is not null AND ReferenceMakeId = @referenceMakeId  THEN 1
        WHEN @referenceModelId is null AND @referenceMakeId is null THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END = 1
```

Comment: Close but no cigar. Your suggestion **looks** like a short circuit condition but does not actually provides it. I've got the worst performance from that structure (35% from 5 different queries)